# Why is my action not getting called in ASP.NET MVC 4 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-ui

I am trying to use `Telerik Kendo ListView` with my ASP.NET MVC 4 web application but I am having trouble getting it populated.  I followed Telerik's Kendo ListView Controller and View examples but `DataSource` of the `ListViewBuilder` is not getting populated.  The following is the relevant code I am using in `FooView`:

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="Foo">        
        <h3>#:FooName#</h3>            
    </div>
</script>

<div class="FooList">
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<FooViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("listView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")    
    .DataSource(dataSource => 
    {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Foo_Read","Foo").Type(HttpVerbs.Get));
        dataSource.PageSize(15);        
    })
    .Pageable()
)
</div>
```

I expect `Foo_Read` to get executed in the `FooController` but it does not.  I suspect this is the reason why the `Kendo ListView` is not getting populated.  So, could someone tell me why my `Foo_Read` action is not getting executed in `FooController`?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm including the relevant Controller code but I simplified it just to see if I could get Visual Studio to break inside of `Foo_Read` but it does not hit my breakpoint.

The relevant FooController.cs code:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
  private Entities db = new Entities();

  public ActionResult Foo_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
  {
    return Json(request, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to share controller code also..

Comment: @ssilas777, I added the controller code for you, but remember, I just want to know why `Foo_Read` does not get called (i.e. Visual Studio does not hit my breakpoint inside of `Foo_Read`).

Comment: its possible kendo isn't resolving the url in the rendering portion, can you paste in the generated <script> tag, from the browser dev panel, so we can see what js is being written?

Comment: Make sure you have added all the necessary script files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It should be the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="Foo">        
        <h3>#:FooName#</h3>            
    </div>
</script>

<div class="FooList">
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<FooViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("listView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")    
    .DataSource(dataSource => 
    {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Foo_Read","Foo").Type(HttpVerbs.Get));
        dataSource.PageSize(15);        
    })
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<FooViewModel>)ViewData["listView"])
    .Pageable()
)
</div>
```

Notice the `.BindTo((IEnumerable<FooViewModel>)ViewData["listView"])` I added.  Apparently that makes a difference.  Not exactly sure why, though.  Telerik's examples did not have that line.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your action is incomplete. Shouldn't it be something along the lines of:

```
public ActionResult Foo_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
  {
    return return Json(db.ToDataSourceResult(request));
  }
```

Well after your comment to my question and seeing your own question, something clicked on my head.

In your solution your're mixing concepts. If you define a datasource to a read controller action, and shouldn't be needing to use the BindTo method. Your solution is probably binding to the ViewData data instead of the Read action returned data. That's why, if I now understand correctly, I think you should be using "AutoBind(true)", like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="Foo">        
        <h3>#:FooName#</h3>            
    </div>
</script>

<div class="FooList">
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<FooViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("listView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template").AutoBind(true)    
    .DataSource(dataSource => 
    {
        dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Foo_Read","Foo").Type(HttpVerbs.Get));
        dataSource.PageSize(15);        
    })
    .Pageable()
)
</div>
```

You might also want to check [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/listview/listview-autobind-false.aspx) and see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Stargazer but that was not the heart of my question.  I wanted to know why `Foo_Read` was not even getting called (i.e. VS was not stopping on my breakpoint inside of `Foo_Read`).  I basically just stubbed it out for the time being.  I did figure out what I was missing and will post my answer shortly.

Comment: Oh, ok then. :) I kind missed the breakpoint also ;) Anyway, I've edit my answer to more accurate one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of kendo you can set .AutoBind(true) then the read event ist executed the first time your listview is loaded.

Alternatively it is possible to call the read method from javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var listView = $("#lstview").data("kendoListView");
    listView.dataSource.read();
});
```